# Loading UIViewController from nib second time messes up frames for UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Ok this is weird. I have never come across something like this before:

I am loading my UIViewController called `LoadVC` like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[LoadVC alloc] init];
```

The first time I do this, the UIImageView in question is perfect, just like I set it in IB:

```
<UIImageView: 0x1ed689c0; frame = (0 -20; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ed68a20>>
```

The negative y offset is intended. The second time I load this view controller, the image view goes crazy:

```
 <UIImageView: 0x1eda3160; frame = (0 -20; 320 436); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+RM+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1eda28d0>>
```

wutup with dat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame of a view is not static, and can change to fit into the environment depending on its resizing mask. The first time you loaded it, it was probably onto a clear screen. The second time it looks like you had something like a navigation bar taking up space, so it was squished vertically. Unless you mean you loaded it twice from the same spot with the same conditions and it you got a different frame each times.